# ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'memory'

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, evm

I'm using `pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.9.0;`

Line `34` with below code:

`event studentAdded(string memory full_name, uint256 memory st_id);`

I'm facing this error. Can anyone help?

`ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'memory' --> contracts/Scorecard.sol:34:31: | 34 | event studentAdded(string memory full_name, uint256 memory st_id); | ^^^^^^`

While removing the `memory` keyword from all arguments of event definitions. I was able to compile successfully but I still can't understand the reasoning behind this. The data location should be either `memory` or `storage` for all the variables right?

Comment: I think the default data-location it uses for arguments defined in the events is `storage` because when we emit the event, the data will be included in the transaction logs which means it will be stored on the blockchain. While when we're using the `memory` data-location for a variable, the data doesn't reside on the blockchain. Can anyone tell me if this is the correct reasoning or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

`memory` key word should be added only for string or array variables.
Not required for uint variables.
Try removing `memory` for uint256 variable.

Answer (score 0):

when declaring any uint type for example:uint256 type you don't need to use memory / calldata as a visibility as they work mostly for strings not numbers.